# Spin off another Task from inside a task in Celery

Tags: celery

My requirement is to create another task from inside a task in Celery. The parameters passed will depend on the output of the parent task. And yes, I want this to be kind of recursive, which stops at some point (based on some IF clause). Is it possible to do that in Celery?

I've looked into the Group/Chord/etc subtask primitives. However, they are not as flexible as I want. 
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can start new tasks within tasks in Celery.  Yes, you can recursively start tasks in Celery.  Yes, you can program if then else conditionals in tasks.  Big question is why would you?

```
@app.task
def mytask(*args, **kwargs):
    if test_basecase(*args, **kwargs):
        return root_case
    else:
        res = mytask.apply_async(*handle(*args), **khandle(**kwargs))
        #probably starting several tasks then joining them
        return res.result
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to schedule as per need. Say I want to run a task once every 2 hours for first two days, then 3 hours apart for 5 days, then 20 hours apart for next 10 days, then stop based on user input any time midway. I should be able to revoke the task when manually told to shutdown.

Comment: You should rewrite your question.